# How to get the ID token of user to a client application after logging in with Vault-OIDC method?

Tags: hashicorp-vault, spring-vault, vault

I have a web application that is in Java. I am successful in authenticating the app via google as the OIDC provider. However, I want the application to connect to google's OIDC via hashicorp vault. I want vault to return an access_token along with the authorisation based on the policy set in vault. Is this possible with vault? I do not see any documentation on how an app can use vault with oidc and get the identity token of the user to the client application. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks a lot in advance :)